# Pagination and orderby with datatables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, datatable

I have a rails 4 application that has the sunspot gem and uses json to respond to the datatables jquery plugin. I'm loosely following this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables

My index in my controller looks like this now:

```
def index
  @search = Product.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:sSearch]
    query.with(:store_id, @collection.id)
    query.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 35)
  end
  @products = @search.results


  @headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq
  @product_data = @products.map{ |product| product[ :data ].values }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json=> {
        "sEcho"               => params[:sEcho].to_i,
        "iTotalRecords"       => @products.count,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords"=> @products.count,
        "aaData"              => @product_data.as_json
      }
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'm trying to get the ordering and paging working with the search block I have, but I can't figure out how to do it. So basically I'm trying to take this code:

```
def fetch_products
   products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
   products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)
end

def page
   params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
end

def per_page
   params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
end

def sort_column
   columns = %w[name category released_on price]
   columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
end

def sort_direction
   params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
end
```

and merge it with what I already have.

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do everything in  your controller and very little reference to your datatable.

If you want to search using sunspot then in the datatable, change the following lines

```
def fetch_products
    products = Product.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    products = products.page(page).per_page(per_page)
  if params[:sSearch].present?

   @search = Product.search do |query|
    query.fulltext params[:sSearch]
    query.with(:store_id, @collection.id)
    query.paginate(:page => params[:page] || 1, :per_page => 35)
   end
  products = @search.results
    end
    products
  end
```

In your controller,

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: ProductsDatatable.new(view_context) }
  end
end
```

Keep other codes in `datatable` as it is.